# Android retrieve text from current view

Tags: android

I have an Android application with a ViewPager that displays motivational messages. I am targeting Oreo and later

This is the view I'm referring to

[image]

I have implemented the "Share Quote" button and it works fine. When I click on the button the following method is called and I can retrieve the displayed quote without issue:

```
 private void shareQuote() {

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

    // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide
    // what to do with it.
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Good Vibrations");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getCurrentQuote());
    //sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.codeofaninja.com");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share quote!"));


}
```

The above code calls the *getCurrentQuote()* method . which returns the displayed info no problem:

```
private String getCurrentQuote() {
    String currentQuote = "currentQuote";

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();



    if (fm != null) {
        currentQuote = "NewCurrentQuote";
        List<Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();
        currentQuote = ""+fragments.size();

        for(int i = fragments.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){

            //Kept getting the following quote...hence the "-1" below...that is for the current quote
            Fragment fragment = fragments.get(i - 1);

            if(fragment != null) {
                // found the current fragment
                currentQuote = "fragment != null";
                // if you want to check for specific fragment class
                if(fragment instanceof QuoteFragment) {

                    currentQuote = fragment.getArguments().getString("quote") + " ~ " + fragment.getArguments().getString("author");


                    setCurrentQuoteString(currentQuote);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

    }


    return currentQuote;
}
```

I have an alarm manager that sends notifications and I am trying to populate those notifications with the same current quote functionality as above. However, I am getting 0 from here:

`currentQuote = ""+fragments.size();`

When not calling this via a button click. Somehow I do not have the relevant "context" when not doing this via the GUI as the share quote button does.

So the short question is when I try create a Service or intent Service to populate the notification like this:

```
.setContentText(getCurrentQuote())
```

I get 0 <-- essentially a null from the getQuotes method, but the same functionality works fine when using the "shareQuote()" method above.

How do I populate a notification automatically with the currently displayed text without some GUI interaction as is the case with the share quote button?

```
public class QuoteViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public QuoteViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you stored your quotes in db  or directly display ?

Comment: Direct display. I retrieve them from a JSON file which I host on git.....

Comment: You can store current quote in Preference and retrieve it when you need to share. I think you parsed json and store into list for Pager Adapter. so you can directly get quote from list instead of fragment manager

Comment: @ Rajasekaran M Please would you provide either sample code or point out a relevant article/tutorial.

Comment: can you add pager adapter? I will add

Comment: @RajasekaranM QuoteViewPagerAdapter added

Comment: I have updated answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can paste the following class as it is:

```
public class PreferenceHelper {

    private static final String PREF = "MyAppPreference";

    private static SharedPreferences getSharedPreference(Context mContext) {
        return mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private static SharedPreferences.Editor getSharedPreferenceForEdit(Context mContext) {
        return getSharedPreference(mContext).edit();
    }

    public static String getCurrentQuote(Context mContext) {
        return getSharedPreference(mContext).getString("CurrentQuote", "");
    }

    public static void setCurrentQuote(Context mContext, String mQuote) {
        getSharedPreferenceForEdit(mContext).putString("CurrentQuote", mQuote).apply();
    }
}
```

And use it wisely like:

To get **Current Quote:** (Call this method when you want to get a current quote)

```
PreferenceHelper.getCurrentQuote(mContext);
```

To save **Current Quote**: (Call this method to save your current quote, better to put this line when you set text into TextView)

```
PreferenceHelper.setCurrentQuote(mContext, currentQuote);
```

Hope it will help you. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Pratik Butani, that makes sense. I'll give it a bash

Comment: Hi @PratikButani tried upvoting, but no joy. Not sure why. Accepted your answer as correct. Thank you again EDIT: This is why I cannot upvote: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @LittleBuddha Thank you. You can come back here when you get enough reputation :) ;)

Answer (score -1):

Store quotes into preference when page changed

```
your_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //get your item form list by position and store your quotes in Preference
                SharedPreferences pref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("your_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                pref.edit().putString("quote","selected_quoate").commit();

            }


            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Share Quotes:

```
 private void shareQuote() {

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

    // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide
    // what to do with it.

     SharedPreferences pref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("your_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, pref.getString("quote");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getCurrentQuote());
    //sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.codeofaninja.com");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share quote!"));


}
```

**Notification**

```
SharedPreferences pref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("your_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


 .setContentText(pref.getString("quote")
```

FYI : Store 0th or initial selected position quote in Preference when open this view on each open